# How to get the client id?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am using the [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) lib and I want to make a private chat just like this: client A sends a message to client B.
There I have a `ws.clients.forEach()` method to broadcast to every client, but how can I get the client id of an individual one?

Answer (score 4):

When you set up your chat system and userA wants to chat with userB, you have to have an identifier that userA users to tell the server they want to chat with userB.  If the `ws` library doesn't provide an easy to use identifier for each connected user, then you need to assign one when the user connects to your server and then keep track of it for each connection in a way you can find the socket that has a given id.  One simple way would be to just create a Map object where key is the ID and value is the socket.  You can then lookup any socket by id.

For example, you could create a unique ID for each incoming socket connection and store it like this:

```
const uuid = require("uuid/v4");

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });
const idMap = new Map();

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    // create uuid and add to the idMap
    ws.uuid = uuid();
    idMap.add(ws.uuid, ws);

    ws.on('close', function() {
        // remove from the map
        idMap.delete(ws.uuid);
    });

    ws.on('message', function(info) {
        try {
            info = JSON.parse(info);
            if (info.action = "send") {
                let dest = idMap.get(info.targetId);
                if (dest) {
                    dest.send(JSON.stringify({action: "message", sender: ws.uuid, data: info.message}));
                }
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("Error processing incoming message", e);
        }
    });
});
```

Then, you could use that uuid value internally to identify which user someone wanted to connect to or send to.

In most real applications, you will also create some sort of login and username.  A unique username could also be used as the id.

Comment: @shengang - Great, glad I could help.